# Laravel Wrapper Whatsapi

Tags: laravel-4, whatsapp

https://github.com/jonnywilliamson/laraWhatsApi

nextChallengeDir has to be writeable. I am using localhost:8000 and I have no such directory /home/user/whatsapi/nextChallengefolder'

See error code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vwewsrmevlu7zj/Screenshot%202015-03-18%2001.23.02.png?dl=0

I would make it writeable with chmod -R 777 but I am unaware of the steps that I need to follow. Can someone help me?

When using Whatsapi with an existing phone number, i also had the problem in the WART registration. Could not detect phone number? Could this also be the problem why it is not working? what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkdir /home/user/whatsapi/nextChallengefolder
chmod 777 /home/user/whatsapi/nextChallengefolder

on app/config/pakages/williamson/config.php put your whatsapp account number and password indetify i normaly use token from RegistreTool.php from
https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/